# Project Server service application missing

Tags: ms-project-server-2013, service-application

I just installed SharePoint and Project Server. When I run configuration wizard to configure service applications, I do not find "Project Server" service application in the list. What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure Project server application separately.
1. Go to System Settings section in CA, click Manage services on server 
2. On the Service list, click Start next to Project Server Application Service.
3. Create a Project Server service application in CA or using PowerShell.